# How to hide a hint when selecting a EditText field in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

[image: Email input field]

I've tried to add

```
if(email.getText().toString().length()!=0){
            email.setHint("");
        }
```

to the onViewCreated method, without success, also tried some thing about EditText OnFocusListener, but it seems like it's deprecated (not sure).
I'm having a hard time to understand how to use all the methods (OnViewCreated, OnCreate... etc) Can someone give me a ~~hint?

This is how my EditText is declared, not sure if the 'final' modifier makes any difference here:

```
final EditText email = view.findViewById(R.id.email);
```

Comment: Please add xml code of edittext

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code it will work.

```
 email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)email.setHint("");
            else email.setHint("Email");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tried inside onViewCreated, didn't work, this is my only lifecycle-related function in this class :( Should I create another function?

Comment: @broom1 Try putting that in onCreate() instead. Also, read the documentation to get familiar with what each method does and when it's called. Also, you mentioned that onViewCreated() is the only method you have, but usually, when you create an activity, it automatically creates the onCreate() method.

Comment: That's actually a fragment! . Couldn't implement that yet but I'll get it somehow, thank you!